# SQL query, sum of of entries with the same type(name)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello i've got 3 different databases which list some different stuff about books. Im looking to find a way to write a SQL function which gives me the sum of books selled in every subsidiary(branch) and only the ones where the total sum is bigger than 2700 + the genre has to be romance. Ive easily figured out the function :

```
SELECT name, SUM(num_sell)  as 'numSum' 
FROM subsidiary,subsidiarybook,book 
WHERE genre= "Romance" 
group by name
```

As you guys cant see all of the datastuff thats going around there, I just want to ask why im always only getting the different names of the branches with the exact same total output. I guess it just takes the total of the first one and not the actual sum belonging to the different names.

Output looks like following :

```
Amazonhive          5163400
Celestial Library   5163400
Cloudcast           5163400
Cosmic Library      5163400
Globalworld         5163400
Imaginetworks       5163400
Leopardworks        5163400
Quick Rooster Media 5163400
Radiantelligence    5163400
Royal Library       5163400
Sphinx Brews        5163400
Spring Harbor ...   5163400
Surge Records       5163400
Tiny Mermaid Arts   5163400
Triumphoods         5163400
Tucan Productions   5163400
```

These values should be different since the sum of these isnt the same for sure. Would appreciate the help. Also how can i check if the sum is > 2700 ?  putting a " AND num_sell >2700" behind the where as it would work normally isnt working in this case.

Comment: **Please** learn how to use `inner join` syntax. Start by denying yourself the use of commas between table names in the `from` clause.

Comment: Because you have used `, ` to "join" all of your tables. That's obsolete syntax and allowed you to make your mistake: you didn't say which rows should join to which (no predicate). So, you effectively did a `CROSS JOIN`. Look up how to use the `INNER JOIN` syntax. It's only been around for over 25 years...

Comment: Note : you say you easily worked out the function. But it's wrong. Always assume You made a mistake, humility makes for better debugging.

Comment: haha yeah .. I mean thats the most obvious thing which comes to your mind when you dont know about the inner join. I knew it existed but since i just started sql i wasnt really aware of the fact that i have to use it in such scenarios ^^

Comment: In SQL if you need 2 or more tables you will JOIN those tables. By accident you have used the **equivalent of** `cross join` and that is not good when summing numbers!!!. You cannot escape needing to know about joins in SQL queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is much to learn from this query.

```
FROM subsidiary, subsidiarybook, book
```

Do NOT use commas between table names in the `FROM` clause. What this does is **MULTIPLY** every row of `subsidiary` by every row of `subsidiarybook` and then **MULTIPLY that result** by every row in `book`. This is why the `sum(num_sell)` is a **constant of 5,163,400** in your current result.

Your `FROM` clause should look *more like this*:

```
FROM subsidiary
INNER JOIN subsidiarybook ON subsidiary.id = subsidiarybook.subsidiary_id
INNER JOIN book ON sb.book_id = book.id
```

Once you have corrected the joins (nb the joins shown above are done in ignorance of the actual column names of your tables!) then you should start to see better results in the `sum(num_sell)`. To filter the result of any aggregation use a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT book.name, SUM(num_sell)  as 'numSum' 
FROM subsidiary
INNER JOIN subsidiarybook ON subsidiary.id = subsidiarybook.subsidiary_id
INNER JOIN book ON sb.book_id = book.id
GROUP BY book.name
HAVING SUM(num_sell) > 2700
```

Now, there may be more to learn. For example `subsidiary` does not appear to be necessary for the final result and **maybe** it can be simplfied to:

```
SELECT book.name, SUM(num_sell)  as 'numSum' 
FROM subsidiarybook
INNER JOIN book ON sb.book_id = book.id
GROUP BY book.name
HAVING SUM(num_sell) > 2700
```

But to know exactly how **to help further we need to know much more about your tables**.

eg. we do not know which table `num_sell` actually comes from

Comment: I just completed my writing which is exactly the same that you have written over here.. :D ++1

Answer (score 1):

The `HAVING` clause will filter the rows after the `GROUP BY`. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Add `HAVING SUM(num_sell) > 2700` after the `GROUP BY` to achieve the required filtering.

An understanding of the logical processing order of `SELECT` statements is a valuable tool. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

Comment: Alright thanks for that, but whats with the same values ? :<

Comment: Yes, the `having` clause is relevant BUT the `cross join`s formed by the commas between tables **will multiply** the num_sell result, so the entire query is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you  are join the table with **cross join** thats why sum is always same. 

please lean about **SQL joins**
Definition of Cross Join
The SQL CROSS JOIN produces a result set which is the number of rows in the first table multiplied by the number of rows in the second table.

[image]